# How to create hotspots in 3d enviroment using threejs?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm a beginner to three.js.I'm trying to build something similar to this https://virtualshowroom.nissan.in/car-selected.html?selectedCar=ext360_deep_blue_pearl. I built everything using three.js, but I'm not able to figure out how to create a hotspot(like the red dot in the above link) and show pop up when you click on it. below is my project code, let me know if anything else is required.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { display: block; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
    
        <script src="./three.js"></script>
        
        <script type="module">
                import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
            import { OrbitControls } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            var renderer,scene,camera;
            
            
           
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xfff6e6)
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            var loader = new GLTFLoader();
            var hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 100)
    scene.add(hlight)

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 100)
    directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0)
    directionalLight.castShadow = true
    scene.add(directionalLight)
            

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 10)
    light.position.set(0, 300, 500)
    scene.add(light)

        var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 10)
    light2.position.set(500, 100, 0)
    scene.add(light2)

    var light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 10)
    light3.position.set(0, 100, -500)
    scene.add(light3)

    var light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 10)
    light4.position.set(-5000, 300, 0)
    scene.add(light4)
    var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
            
            


    var loader = new GLTFLoader(); 
            loader.load( './scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) 
                        { 
                scene.add( gltf.scene ); 
            }, undefined, function ( error ) { console.error( error ); } );
           
            

// load a image resource
            

camera.position.z = 5;
            

            
            var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
            
            
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give a walkthrough on the steps required to get the desired effect since I have done it a few times myself.

1. define a 3d point in your scene where the hotspot should be. You can optionally nest this in a an other Object3D to make sure it scales, moves and rotates with the model / parent.
2. Add a plane to this point load a image texture to this plane. and there you have your visible hotspot
3. update the hotspots to make sure they are always looking at the camera by using the `lookAt` function.
4. when the user clicks the screen cast a raycast against all the hotspots you have in your scene. Easiest way to do this is by storing all your hotspots in an array.
5. When the raycast hits a hotspot get the location either of the hitpoint or the hotspots location. Transform that to screen coordinates. Search on stackoverflow how to do this. I am sure there is a post about this.
6. Final step display your html on the correct location you obtained from the previous step.

The advantage of this method is that the hotspot will integrate nicely with the model in your scene. Since html based hotspots will always be on top of the scene.

That is about all that is to it. Let me know if you need any further clarification!

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, i"ll try the above steps to implement and let you know in case if I get any issue. after getting coordinates using ray casting, can you please tell how to create that box which has the information, which will appear when you hit on a hotspot. as I'm new to javascript, I'm still figuring out things, if you give the link of any tutorial or post you know is also fine.

Comment: no worries happy to help. Just make sure the accept the answer if it solved your issues :) 
regarding the box containing the text it is best to have this as an html element in the document with a fixed or absolute position. And then used the screen coordinates you got to set the left and top style parameters of the html element. to make sure the position matches. And make sure the you add a class with hidden style to hide the element and on a raycast hit remove this class so the element shows up. Hope this makes sense. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: I'm still stuck with creating a box when you hit the hotspot. somehow I can manage to get the hotspot position, but I'm stuck on how to create the box and let that box show up when you click a hotspot and that box also should have a close button. can you please help me with it?

Comment: Yeah I see, but this is probably best to ask as a new question since it requires its own techniques and logic. Tag me with a new question and i can take a look at it.

Answer (score 5):

Those “hotspots” as you call them are [`Annotations`](https://manu.ninja/webgl-three-js-annotations/) where the annotation content is basically pure HTML.
[image]

The [tutorial in the link](https://manu.ninja/webgl-three-js-annotations/) is probably the best step-by-step readiness you can follow to learn how to do it in your scene.